# how to upload few files to server at once?

Tags: android

I want to upload few files(Imagefiles) to server at once

I already had success upload one file to server but i can't upload few files to

server now.

How to revise my code for uploading few files to server??

Android side

```
public class serverConnection {
    private Bitmap compressedBitmap;
    private ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapList;
    private String boundary = "******";

    private String twoHyphens = "--";
    private String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    private int bitmapListCount = 0;
    private String virtualName = "hong's.jpg";


    public serverConnection(ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapList){
      this.bitmapList = bitmapList;
        Log.d("bitemapList is " , bitmapList.size() + "");
        connectionThread();
    }

    private void connectionThread(){
        new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                uploadImage();
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void uploadImage() {
        try {



                URL url = new URL("http://192.168.11.19:8080/appTest/uploadImageandroid.do");
                HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                http.setDoInput(true);
                http.setDoOutput(true);
                http.setUseCaches(false);
                http.setRequestMethod("POST");
                http.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                http.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE","multipart/form-data");
                http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

                //write data
                DataOutputStream requestStream = new DataOutputStream(http.getOutputStream());

                requestStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            for(int i=0;i < bitmapList.size() ; i++) {
                requestStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + virtualName + "\"" + lineEnd);

                requestStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);



            compressedBitmap = (Bitmap) bitmapList.get(0);
                compressedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, requestStream);
                requestStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            }
            requestStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);



                requestStream.flush(); //finish upload


                int ch;
                InputStream inputStream = http.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
                while((ch = inputStream.read()) != -1){
                    b.append((char)ch);

                }
                String s = b.toString();
                System.out.println(s);
                requestStream.close();

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

server side

```
 public String upload(Part part) {  
        try{    


        reName = "dd";
        saveFileDir = new File(savePath);

        if(saveFileDir.exists()){
        System.out.println("folder exist");

        }

            fileName = extractFileName(part); 
            StringTokenizer sz = new StringTokenizer(fileName , File.separator);


                while(sz.hasMoreTokens()){

                        fileName = sz.nextToken();

                }


                reName = reName + fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf(".") , fileName.length()); 

                System.out.println("fileName is modified From " + fileName + " To " + reName);
                 part.write(savePath + File.separator + reName); 


        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            //flag = false;
        }
         return reName;      

    }

     public String savePathed(){
         return savePath + File.separator + fileName;
     }

     private String extractFileName(Part part) { 
            String contentDisp = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
            System.out.println("part-Header: " + contentDisp);
            String[] items = contentDisp.split(";"); 
            for (String s : items) {
                if (s.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
                    return s.substring(s.indexOf("=") + 2, s.length()-1);
                }
            }
            return "";
        }
```